# Set Application Name for SQL Server Connections when connecting pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, flask, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have a flask app which uses SQLAlchemy engines to exectue some queries to mssql.
My connection string is the following:

> "mssql+pyodbc://uid:pwd@server/database?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"

The above works and the queries get executed successfully. However if I check from the DB side the Application Name I get Python. Is there a way to change this ?

I have tried the following combinations strings:

> "mssql+pyodbc://uid:pwd@server/database?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;App=MyAPP"

> "mssql+pyodbc://uid:pwd@server/database?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server:ApplicationName=MyApp"

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `&App=MyApp` instead of `;App=MyApp`

Comment: If you were doing things the SQLAlchemy way, via `URL.create()`, you could also add `"APP": "MyAPP"` to the `query` dictionary.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies, they both work!